# What is the use of the offset in the bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to the bootstrap below is my code

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
  <div class="section-heading">
     <h2>About us</h2>
     <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

So over here what these offset-2 will do?Is It compulsory to use??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset adds space to the left of your element.

Imagine your element is the "xxxx" in the examples below:

xxxx--------   (col-lg-4, no offset)

--xxxx------ (col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-4)

Comment: thank you for your reply but it is necessary to use ??

Comment: Well, no. It's just the easiest way to add space to the left of your element because it leverages bootstrap's grid system. It isn't "necessary" to use, but if you are utilizing bootstrap to it's fullest extent then you will almost definitely use offset at some point. Look at these examples: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/